# Grid CSS having the last two items to take the remaining space

Tags: css, css-grid

I have this layout

```
X X X X
X X X X
A B
```

With grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);

But I actually want the two last items to take the full width of the remaining space, like :

```
X X X X
X X X X 
A A B B
```

Sorry for the dumb question, gonna watch a complete course but right now I really need to get this done

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `:nth-last-child()` and `grid-column:span2;` if your markup is always the same.

```css
body>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

div {
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 3px;
}

div div:nth-last-child(1),
div div:nth-last-child(2) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>x</div>
  <div>x</div>
  <div>x</div>
  <div>x</div>
  <div>x</div>
  <div>x</div>
  <div>x</div>
  <div>x</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can generate a CSS grid using [this website.](https://grid.layoutit.com/)

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) is a complete guide about CSS Grid.

Added a red border, margin and height, so the desired grid is visible.

```css
div{
border: 5px solid red;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "X X X X"
    "X X X X"
    "A A B B";
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
.X { grid-area: X; }
.A { grid-area: A; }
.B { grid-area: B; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="X">XXXX</div>
  <div class="A">AA</div>
  <div class="B">BB</div>
</div>
```